# Transpose Columns to Rows by blank

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I need to transpose vertical data from column B to horizontal data.

**My table looks like this:**

```
 85.98 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 97.62 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
100.00 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
100.00 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
       |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 89.81 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 78.70 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
100.00 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
       |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 94.32 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
       |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
       |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
       |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 90.91 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
  0.00 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 88.54 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 76.96 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 94.32 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 89.11 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
```

**And I want it to look like this:**

```
 85.98 |  97.62 | 100.00 | 100.00 |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 89.81 |  78.70 | 100.00 |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 94.32 |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
       |        |        |        |        |        |
-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
 90.91 |   0.00 |  88.54 |  76.96 |  94.32 |  89.11 |
```

**I am using the following code:**

```
  Sub Transpose()
  Dim t As Range, u As Range
  c = ActiveCell.Column
  fr = ActiveCell.Row
  lr = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
  r = fr
  Do
      Set t = Cells(r, c)
      Set u = t.End(xlDown)
      Range(t, u).Copy
      t.Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
      r = u.End(xlDown).Row
  Loop While r < lr
  Application.CutCopyMode = False 
  End Sub
```

The problem is `.End(xlDown)` doesn't work because there are single rows of data. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: looks like your do while condition is in the wrong spot

Comment: It is `xlDown`. Lower case L

Comment: Why do you want a gap between `94.32` and `90.91`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be accomplished with this...

```
Sub TransposeData()
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
'Change the first row as required. C1 in the below line assumes that the data start from Row1 in Column C.
For Each rng In Range("C1:C" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1).Areas
    rng.Copy
    rng.Cells(1).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
Next rng
Application.CutCopyMode = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```